# MySQL no recoge datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentado recoger datos para mostrar en mi pagina comentarios pero no los recoge la tabla...

¿Me podéis ayudar?

Os adjunto código y captura de base datos.

```
<?php
$host_name = 'dbxxxxxx.db.1and1.com';
$database = 'dbxxxxx';
$user_name = 'dboxxxx';
$password = '<xxxx>';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('<p>Error al conectar con servidor MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
} else {
    echo '<p>Se ha establecido la conexión al servidor MySQL con éxito.</p >';
}
?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Deja un mensaje</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<FORM ACTION="procesar_mensaje.php" METHOD=POST>
<B>Nombre de usuario:</B>
<INPUT TYPE=text SIZE=20 NAME="usuario">
<BR>
<B>Escribe tu mensaje:</B>
<BR>
<TEXTAREA ROWS=10 COLS=70 NAME="mensaje"></TEXTAREA>
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE=submit VALUE="Enviar mensaje">
</FORM>

<HR>

<?PHP

$host_name = 'dbxxxxx.db.1and1.com';
$database = 'dbxxxxx';
$user_name = 'dboxxxxx';
$password = '<xxxxx>';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('<p>Error al conectar con servidor MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
} else {
    echo '<p>Se ha establecido la conexión al servidor MySQL con éxito.</p >';
}
if ($conexion)
{
    $resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT id, usuario, fecha, mensaje FROM comentarios ORDER BY id DESC", $conexion);
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado))
    {
        echo "<B>Mensaje</B> #" . $fila[0] . "; ";
        echo "<B>Escrito por:</B> " . $fila[1] . "; ";
        echo "<B>Fecha:</B> " . $fila[2] . "; ";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo $fila[3];
        echo "<HR>";
    }
}


?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

[image: base datos]

Comment: Seria bueno que editarás la pregunta y añadieras los errores y como aplicaste los cambios de la respuesta que te dejo el compañero. Más que nada por saber que esta fallando.

Comment: @xerif tienes razón pero no sabia hacerlo,jajajaja intentaba responder por aquí y me daba error...voy a editar. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiene al menos dos errores bien marcados en su código.

- Su variable o enlace de conexión es `$connect` y no `$conexion` , debe modificar a un solo nombre. *(conexión para mi respuesta)*
- [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) espera como primer parámetro la conexión y luego la `query` a ejecutar , su error ? le está enviando los parámetros equivocadamente.

*Posible código final*

```
//variable conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('<p>Error al conectar con servidor MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
} else {
    echo '<p>Se ha establecido la conexión al servidor MySQL con éxito.</p >';
}
if ($conexion)
{
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT id, usuario, fecha, mensaje FROM comentarios ORDER BY id DESC");
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado))
    {
        echo "<B>Mensaje</B> #" . $fila[0] . "; ";
        echo "<B>Escrito por:</B> " . $fila[1] . "; ";
        echo "<B>Fecha:</B> " . $fila[2] . "; ";
        echo "<BR>";
        echo $fila[3];
        echo "<HR>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Voy a probar y te cuento

Comment: Dev. Joel he corregido código y la tabla sigue sin recoger datos....¿La tabla está bien? Vuelvo a pegar código corregido:

Comment: yo lo que quiero es que los usuarios puedan dejar comentarios en la página y si fuese posible publicar fotos que hagan del evento que tengamos en ese momento....pero creo que de momento si consigo hacer que se recojan comentarios y se muestren automáticamente me doy por contento, luego ya irán las fotos¡ Gracias!

Comment: @rolmo no veo la necesidad de editar mi respuesta. Si tiene cambios hágalo en su pregunta. Así yo modificare mi respuesta quizá para explicar los posibles detalles del por qué.

Comment: Perdona @devjoel....ha sido sin querer, no sabia como responder y me he liado. Te pido mill disculpas, en ningún momento quería tocar nada de lo que has puesto...me he liado un poco. disculpas de nuevo. y muchas gracias por tu paciencia. Saludos

Comment: buenos días. Sigo sin poder recoger los datos de la tabla...no se si el problema esta en la tabla o en el código....el tema es que conecta con la base de datos pero que me dice que la conexión es correcta, pero luego no recoge los comentarios....¿Que puede se? Viste la captura de la tabla?saludos

Comment: disculpa @dev.joel estoy con fiebre....gripe, en cuanto me encuentre mejor hago captura y te envío.  gracias por tu paciencia

Comment: Hola a todos!!  @dev.Joel! ya estoy por aquí, ya estoy mejor...llevo todo el día con el código haciendo pruebas...y nada ahora me sale error en linea 3

Comment: <?php

$conexion = mysqli_connect("dbxxxxxx.db.1and1.com", "dboxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
mysqli_select_db("dbxxxxxx", $conexion);

if ($conexion)
{
 mysqli_query("INSERT INTO comentarios (usuario, mensaje) VALUES ('".$_POST["usuario"]."', '".$_POST["mensaje"]."')", $conexion);
 header("Location: comentarios.php");
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>

Comment: uff!! no puedo pegar todo el código del html+php.... ¿Como os lo pongo?

Comment: era por enseñarte el código como quedo después de que me dieses una posible solución...que sigue sin funcionar....disculpa si no me se expresar bien...

Comment: disculpa....no se como responderte....en el chat....

Comment: necesito 20 reputaciones para hablar por chat....

Comment: Gracias de todas formas

Comment: @rolmo viendo sus comentarios , tiene errores en otra parte de su código _insert_  que no corresponden a la pregunta. lo que preguntó se respondió. si tiene otra duda y como no puede entrar al chat tendría que formular una nueva pregunta y marcar como aceptada si es que solucione lo que se pregunto con mi respuesta.

Comment: Vale gracias!!! @Dev. Joel. Saludos